# Pressing the PageExpander-Button adds another Navbar

Tags: bootstrap-4, xpages, lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse

every time I press the Page Expander or any other button on my XPage a new navbar gets added. Can somebody explain this.

Here is the code for the PagerExpander:

```
<xe:pagerExpand id="pagerExpand1" for="viewPanel"
        style="position: right;">
    </xe:pagerExpand>
```

If you are wondering which Navbar, I mean this one: 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

I can't see the connection between expanding some entrys and adding a new Navbar.

Thx in advance

Comment: Please, provide more of the source code, where exactly did you insert that pageExpand. also consider to use it as facet https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/user/extlib_controlref_pagerexpand.html

Comment: Since this happens for any button you should look for a dangling event handler somewhere